# DirectX Overlay - Font Wrapper Error

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to overlay text into a DirectX Game and i found FontWrapper on the internet.
Link : https://fw1.codeplex.com/

I included the header file `FW.h` and made `Main.cpp`

code inside Main.cpp :

```
#include "FW.h"


void drawText(ID3D11Device *pDevice, ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext) {
    IFW1Factory *pFW1Factory;
    HRESULT hResult = FW1CreateFactory(FW1_VERSION, &pFW1Factory);

    IFW1FontWrapper *pFontWrapper;
    hResult = pFW1Factory->CreateFontWrapper(pDevice, L"Arial", &pFontWrapper);

    pFontWrapper->DrawString(
        pContext,
        L"Hello World",// String
        128.0f,// Font size
        100.0f,// X position
        50.0f,// Y position
        0xff0099ff,// Text color, 0xAaBbGgRr
        0// Flags (for example FW1_RESTORESTATE to keep context states unchanged)
    );

    pFontWrapper->Release();
    pFW1Factory->Release();
}
```

after that I'm getting these errors : 
[Error that i get](https://i.gyazo.com/7c3c5cd7629bb67c77bbaee48cfdac64.png)

PS:I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the code inside Main.cpp , i copied it from the official website where they show a sample.
if you don't know how to fix this , then please tell me how to overlay a text on a directX Game , just a little text and then i will do the rest.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I'm sure you can get that project to work, but you are just missing a project-to-project reference. You can also use [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the ``SpriteFont`` class per the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Drawing-text)

Comment: thanks Walbourn, but i found that "DirectX Tool Kit" is so complicated .. do i need all this to draw a simple text on a directX Game? 
thanks

Comment: Drawing text with DirectX Tool Kit is three lines of code, while F1W1FontWrapper requires creating a two COM objects. Direct3D draws single pixel points, single pixel width lines, and filled/textured triangles. Everything else ultimately drawn using those.

Comment: Alright @ChuckWalbourn i will try it out ... one more question : does it support DirectX9 games?

Comment: DirectX Tool Kit and ``F1W1FontWrapper `` require Direct3D 11. The legacy D3DX9 library font implementation uses the same kind of 'sprite' solution as DirectX Tool Kit's ``SpriteFont``.